# How to read data from JSON file and use it in Cypress test

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm writing a login test with different types of users and I have a JSON file with user credentials for different users.

```
[
    { 
        "userType":"admin,
        "email":"admin@test.com",
        "password":"test1234"
    },
    { 
        "userType":"employee,
        "email":"employee@test.com",
        "password":"test1234"
    }
]
```

These are my tests:

```
it('Login test - admin user', () => {
    cy.get("[type='email']").type('admin@test.com');
    cy.get("[type='password']").type('test1234');
    cy.get("[id='login']").click();
    cy.url().should('includes', '/dashboard');
});

it('Login test - employee user', () => {
    cy.get("[type='email']").type('employee@test.com');
    cy.get("[type='password']").type('test1234');
    cy.get("[id='login']").click();
    cy.url().should('includes', '/welcome');
});
```

I want to pass the user type and fetch the credentials for the user and use it in the test. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and here's my approach. It's not an exact solution for your use-case as I had my data in .txt file that needed some splitting, you can adjust it easily with `JSON.parse()`:

1. Create a new [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands), let's call it `getUser` that will use a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task):

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getUser", () => {
    return cy.task("getUser").then((user) => {
        return user;
    });
  });
```

2. In `plugins/index.js` define the new `getUser` task:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
var users = []
var usersLoaded;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    getUser(){
      if (!usersLoaded && fs.existsSync("<<path>>/users.txt")) {
        var usersFile = fs.readFileSync("<<path>>/users.txt", 'utf8')
        users = usersFile.split('\n');  //here you might need to adjust for json parsing
        usersLoaded = true;
      }
      return users.shift()
    }
}
```

Notice the `usersLoaded` boolean and the `users` array that are used. Basically I loaded all users and than popped them one by one from the array (using `array.shift()`).

3. Then in your test you can just use

```js
cy.getUser().then((user) => {
  cy.log(user)
  //your code here
})
```

4. You'll run into another problem: iterating through the users in order to do your job with it. For that my approach was something like:

```js
Cypress._.times(10, () => { //where 10 is the number of users you have in your file
  describe('Test', () => {
    it('Login ', () => {
      cy.getUser().then((user) => {
        //your code here
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I chose this approach so I'd have a different test for each user. The downside is that you need to hardcode the number of users.

I'm not an expert in cypress, this was just my approach. There might be a smarter way of accomplishing this. I basically came up with this after researching the [cypress RWA auth tests](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tests/ui/auth.spec.ts) which uses something like `cy.database("find", "users")`